# Using cloud data warehouse as back-end for website

Tags: architecture, data-warehouse, website-performance

I am building a website, where the main data source is Snowflake, a cloud data warehouse.
This cannot be changed, but we can add other technologies.

There is a lot of data in Snowflake, and the calculations for each web page are quite complicated.

We believe that computing everything in real-time would not be acceptable for the user experience (too slow).

Therefore we want to pre-compute some elements, as much as possible.

The limiting factor for pre-computation is a combinatorial wall, since there are many options that influence the final data being displayed (date ranges, preferences, etc.).

The question is: **what type of architecture can alleviate these problems?**

For instance:

- Use vectorized Python stored procedures in Snowflake to speed up calculations?
- ﻿﻿Pre-compute all the data for a page and store it (serialized) in an OLTP DB?
- ﻿﻿Collect information on which pages are used by which user to reduce the need for pre-computation? (Only pre-compute the pages that are used most.)

Comment: Are there combinations of options that are (likely to be) use significantly more often, also across users? If so, you can use caching to avoid recalculating the same data over and over again.

Comment: All those ideas will help. What we can't realistically tell you is which ones will help the most, and which ones will cost the most (both in terms of development time and ongoing cost).